# Getting link address using phantomjs

Tags: python, web-scraping, phantomjs

I am trying to get article urls for each div on this page : https://www.google.com/trends/home/all/IN 
I am able to get image link and title, but for article link it gives

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "google.py", line 25, in getGooglerends
    print s.find_elements_by_class_name('image-wrapper').get_attribute('href')
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'get_attribute'
```

Code:

```
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS('/usr/local/bin/phantomjs')
driver.set_window_size(1124, 850)
driver.get("https://www.google.com/trends/home/all/IN")
trend = {}
def getGooglerends():
    try:
    #Does this line makes any sense
        #element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(lambda driver: driver.find_elements_by_class_name('md-list-block ng-scope'))
        for s in driver.find_elements_by_class_name('md-list-item-block'):
            print s.find_element_by_tag_name('img').get_attribute('src')
            print s.find_element_by_tag_name('img').get_attribute('alt')
            print s.find_elements_by_class_name('image-wrapper').get_attribute('href')
    except:
        import traceback
        print traceback.format_exc()
getGooglerends()
```

Any suggestion for getting article link from anchor tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`WebDriver.find_elements_by_class_name`](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.find_elements_by_class_name) returns a list of elements, not a single element.

```
s.find_elements_by_class_name('image-wrapper')
              ^
```

Use [`WebDriver.find_element_by_class_name`](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.find_element_by_class_name) instead of [`WebDriver.find_elements_by_class_name`](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.find_elements_by_class_name).

```
s.find_element_by_class_name('image-wrapper')
```

Comment: thanks a lot, can you please explain `element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(lambda driver: driver.find_elements_by_class_name('md-list-block ng-scope'))` is it required?

Comment: @nlper, If the element is not rendered immediately, it is required. Test yourself with the page.